# Blurring an image with a non-uniform filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I am new on Stackoverflow and this is my first question, so please be patient with me.

I want to blur an image with a non uniform filter.However, I have not fully understood what is a non-uniform filter and I would like to ask what does exactly an non-uniform filter do and how can that be intepreted in terms of a code.
I want to implement this in Matlab. Hereby is an example of my code.

A non-uniform kernel would be that

```
init= imread('cameraman.jpg');
initial = rgb2gray(init);
sigma=3;
H_filt = fspecial('gaussian',[5 5], sigma);
```

or would be restricted to only one dimension?

```
init= imread('cameraman.jpg');
initial = rgb2gray(init);
sigma=3;
H_filt = fspecial('gaussian',[5 1], sigma);
```

Thanks in advance fellows!!

Comment: That's a 1D filter, but I don't know if that's what you mean by non-uniform. Probably not. Can you give a citation for the paper you are referencing?

Comment: @chappjc, I guess all the filters except the box window in time/spatial domain are non-uniform filters...

Comment: Basically that has not to do with a paper. In terms of a project, I am asked to blur an image with a self defined non uniform blurring filter. I am not sure if it means the direction to which it will be applied(thats why I posted the two examples) or it has to do with the type of the filter. This is why I picked the gaussian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Non uniform blur kernels**

A non-uniform blur kernel is a kernel that is *not constant* over the *whole image*.

To take some examples:

- out-of-focus blur kernel size depends on the distance between the camera and the scene point (usually referred to as Z). This phenomenon can be exploited by shape-from-defocus algorithms;
- a moving object in a static scene can be subject to motion blur, while there is obviously no blur in the static parts. Different moving objects can indeed have different motion blurs;
- a camera lens usually produces better (sharper) images in its center with respect to its borders.

**How to generate a non uniformly blurred image**

It depends on how many blur kernels your image has, and what kind of blur you want to emulate.

- Defocus blur (function of the camera-scene point distance) can be simulated by ray tracing software.
- If you wan to generate non-uniform blur by post-processing (convolution), then you need to:

  1. Get the blur kernel for the pixel at hand `(i,j)`: for example `sigma_ij = f(i,j)`
  2. Convolve your input image (the sharp, clean one) by this blur kernel: `H_ij = fspecial('gaussian', [some large size], sigma_ij])`
  3. Write the result to your output image: `I_final[i,j] = I_blurred_with_Hij[i,j]`
  4. Proceed to the next pixel.

In some cases, you can cut this greedy loop with correct assumptions (blur size limit, only two or 3 possible blurs in the image...).

Answer (score 1):

Usually they mean a filter which isn't constant for each pixel -> It is not uniform spatially.
Try to implement a Gaussian Blur which its Standard Deviation is different at each pixel.

A fast way to do so is using `colfilt`.

If you need more help let me know.